# Magento 2: Cart is allowing update more than available qty

Tags: magento2.3, addtocart, shopping-cart, inventory, qty

I am having very odd issue. I am using Magento 2.3.2. I have migrated data from magento 1.9.3.

While I am adding product to cart, It works perfect, however whenever I try to update qty from cart it allows the qty limit to "Maximum allow qty" although products are not having Qty(s). Maximum allow qty is 10000 so I am able to add qty till 10000 but most of the products are having 250 Qty(s)

[image]

Please help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Any Idea about this ?